# What is the JavaScript way of iterating Array of Objects and return new Object with merged arrays by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the JavaScript way of iterating Aarray of Objects and return new Object with merged arrays by Object key?

Original Array of Objects:

```
this.obj = [
    {
        "name": "test name 1",
        "teams": [{
            "manage": false,
            "name": "my test team",
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "test name 2",
        "teams": [{
            "manage": false,
            "name": "TEAM2",
        }]
    }
];
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "teams": [{
        "manage": true,
        "name": "TEAM2",
    }, {
        "manage": false,
        "name": "my test team",
    }]
}
```

I managed to accomplish this with two nested loops and one variable. What is JavaScript way for this scenario ?

```
let data = {'teams': []};

for (var i = this.obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (var p = this.obj[i].teams.length - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
     data.teams.push(this.groups[i].teams[p]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` to return object as result.

```js
var obj = [{"name":"test name 1","teams":[{"manage":false,"name":"my test team"}]},{"name":"test name 2","teams":[{"manage":false,"name":"TEAM2"}]}];

var result = obj.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.teams = (r.teams || []).concat(e.teams)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You don't need an extra object for the accumulator here; `obj.reduce((acc, itm) => acc.concat(itm.teams), []);`

Comment: Actually, if the OP ever wanted to do this for multiple keys at once maybe the object would be easier

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the array and the loop through the keys of the object. If a leys is unequal than `name`, take the content an concat it to the result array with the same key.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "test name 1", "teams": [{ "manage": false, "name": "my test team", }] }, { "name": "test name 2", "teams": [{ "manage": false, "name": "TEAM2", }] }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'name') {
            result[k] = (result[k] || []).concat(o[k]);
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, I would probably go with arrays **`Map`** method.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "test name 1", "teams": [{ "manage": false, "name": "my test team", }] }, { "name": "test name 2", "teams": [{ "manage": false, "name": "TEAM2", }] }],
result = {};

data.map(function(obj){
result.teams = (result.teams || []).concat(obj.teams)
});
console.log(result);
```

Although, using **`reduce`**  method will give you the solution. it is having it is us used for the different purpose. You can read about it more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce